# How to get cpu, gpu and os full name

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to get the full name of CPU, GPU and OS in Java?

For example:

- CPU: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100 CPU @ 3.60GHZ 3.60GHZ`
- GPU: `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti 6GB`
- OS: `Windows 10 PRO x64 2004`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.getProperty("os.arch")` gets you something like `x86_64`.

`System.getProperty("os.name")` gets you something like `Mac OS X`.

`System.getProperty("sun.cpu.endian")` gets you `little` (and this is a non-standard property name).

Beyond that, the answer is mostly 'no, you cant do that'.

What you can do is check which OS you are on, and launch OS and architecture specific tools, either via the native interface (JNI) or by using `ProcessBuilder` to execute command line tools that are known to be installed by default on the OS you're on to get this information.

For example, *IF* you know you're on some posix installation (for example, mac, or linux), you can use processbuilder to run `/usr/bin/uname -a`, which gets you something like:

`Darwin YourSystemName.local 19.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

You can run `/usr/sbin/sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` to get something like `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1060NG7 CPU @ 1.20GHz`.

However, `/usr/sbin/sysctl` may not be on your system. It definitely won't be there on a windows box, it may not be there on various flavours of linux.

Trying to test such a setup is going to be extremely tricky. You'd need hundreds of deployments (all flavours of linux you care to support, various mac versions, a bunch of windows versions, and more).

Quite the complex project, in other words!

I'd consider using a library that took care of all this, such as [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi). OSHI is a free [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)-based (native) Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this using the OSHI library? I can't find anything on the internet about it.

Comment: Err.. click the link, read the documentation? If there's something specific in the docs that you don't understand, open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently used the OSHI api https://github.com/oshi/oshi it provides you many api for getting the details related to CPU information and OS.

One more alternative is  SIGAR API by Hyperic.

Comment: @krystek try this link https://code.dblock.org/2010/06/23/introducing-oshi-operating-system-and-hardware-information-java.html It has basic api usages and the information relevant to your question..

Comment: that blog post is over 10 years old. The link in the answer you replied to is to the same project.

Comment: @Daniel Widdis.. just helped out by some of the api info that would let krystek to start something..

Comment: Except that code doesn't work. `getProcessors()` was changed in 2015. :).   A better link is the [README](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/README.md#usage) linked from the project's home page in the answer above, which directs users to use [SystemInfoTest](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/d1be3a4204ed1054e6c789c69708c987240db50d/oshi-core/src/test/java/oshi/SystemInfoTest.java#L93) for examples.